# sp_configure set at code execution - Pro/con's of turning on/off

Tags: sql-server, security

The right answer of course is 'it depends', but on the surface it seems to make sense to turn on/off some options when needed as the code sample below for Ole Automation Procedures would do. Could also be xp_cmdshell or Ad Hoc Distributed Queries among a handful of others. EDIT: The question - is this a good or bad idea? why/why not

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

--Sample Code:
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
 Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', '<URL>&output=XML','false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select CONVERT(xml,@ResponseText)

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object;

GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: What problem (or perceived problem) are you attempting to solve by doing this? I suspect this question may be closed  as being a matter of opinion.

Comment: Minimizing surface area for security. Ole Automation and xp_cmdshell among others are switched off at install for security purposes, with recommendation to turn on if needed and other security concerns addressed. But those suggestions seem to be 'turn it on and leave it on" as opposed to turning on/off at point of execution. On off at execution seems like a good idea - but why don't best practices mention this? Is it a bad idea, and if so why?

Answer (score 1):

A) Those options can only be switch by logins with elevated permissions. Therefore to alter them at run-time the application must run with elevated permissions. This is a security risk.

B) Actions performed in this way run in the DBMS's process. Any instability (bug, exception) they cause will affect the stability of SQL Server and *all* clients it is serving.

Comment: Excellent points - thank you Michael!